# Swing Events Trouble

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I am new to Java and am developing a java swing application.

The main frame (JFrame) has a text box and an OK button. There is some long processing to be done when the focus from the text box is lost as well as different long processing when the OK button is clicked. Now if the user enters a value in the text box and clicks the OK button directly, ideally, first the focus lost event is fired and then the event on the OK button. The problem is that while the focus lost event is running a joption frame comes up asking the user for some input, but even before user enters the input here, the OK button event starts executing leading to problems in the application. How can I serialize the event calls.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please post your code in http://sscce.org/ form

Comment: that's not related to event sequence, your logic needs a thorough re-design: the button must not start the process before the user input (and its processing) is terminated

Comment: kleopatra - how do i achieve what you are saying?

Comment: ehh .. probably don't understand the question - in the simplest case have property somewhere which triggers the end-processing once the user wanted to start it (but couldn't because the intermediate process wasn't yet ready)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies within the concept of the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). For long running work loads, check out the [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class.